# Input and formatted output

Tags: python-3.x

now I just can get the ". " in after the number, I've tried many different ways it just keep showing errors or to much spaces.

```
current_price = int(input())

last_months_price = int(input())



price_change = current_price - last_months_price

monthly_mortagae = (current_price*0.045)/12

print('This house is','${0}'.format(current_price),'The change is','${0}'.format(price_change),'since last month.')

print('The estimated monthly mortgage is','${}'.format('%0.2f' %monthly_mortagae))
```

Input

```
200000

210000
```

Your output

```
This house is $200000 The change is $-10000 since last month.

The estimated monthly mortgage is $750.00
```

Expected output

```
This house is $200000. The change is $-10000 since last month.

The estimated monthly mortgage is $750.00.
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not just insert it in the string, and use only one format:

```
print('This house is ${0}. The change is ${1} since last month.'.format(current_price, price_change))

print('The estimated monthly mortgage is ${:0.2f}.'.format(monthly_mortagae))
```

With just one print statement:

```
print('This house is ${0}. The change is ${1} since last month.\nThe estimated monthly mortgage is ${2:0.2f}.'.format(current_price, price_change, monthly_mortagae))
```

Comment: Thank you. I actually Played around with it for a bit and figured it out. but I should have shorten it up a bit. Thank you very much for responding.

Answer (score 0):

### Use modern `f-strings`:

- [f-Strings: A New and Improved Way to Format Strings in Python](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/#f-strings-a-new-and-improved-way-to-format-strings-in-python)

  - It's easier to see where all the variables are being used
  - No clunky type declarations (e.g. `%s`)
  - Easily format numbers to the correct number of decimal places, as shown in the code below

### Given:

```
current_price = 200000
last_months_price = 210000

price_change = current_price - last_months_price
monthly_mortagae = (current_price*0.045)/12
```

### f-strings:

#### 2-lines:

```
print(f'This house is ${current_price}. The change is ${price_change} since last month.'.replace('$-','-$'))
print(f'The estimated monthly mortgage is ${monthly_mortagae:0.02f}.'.replace('$-','-$'))
```

#### 1-line:

```
print(f"""This house is ${current_price}. The change is ${price_change} since last month.
The estimated monthly mortgage is ${monthly_mortagae:0.02f}.""".replace('$-','-$'))
```

- Using `"""some text"""` allows for a standard carriage return instead of `\n`

```
print("""this
is
a
sentence""")

this
is
a
sentence
```

### Output:

```
This house is $200000. The change is -$10000 since last month.
The estimated monthly mortgage is $750.00.
```

- Using `.replace('$-','-$')` gets the negative sign to the left of $.

Comment: Thank you. I actually Played around with it for a bit and figured it out. but I should have shorten it up a bit. Thank you very much for responding.

Comment: @stduffy06yahoocom note the new f-string properly places the negative sign